# Graphite is plotting increments from Logstash in float

Tags: graphite, logstash, statsd

I was trying to mimic this [logstash.net/docs/1.1.0/tutorials/metrics-from-logs](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.0/tutorials/metrics-from-logs)

I have following setup

nginx(app server) ==sends the increment==>Etsy statsD=====>Graphite

This setup is working fine since graph is being plotted just fine but not correctly. According to above configuration, I understand the graph step value should be integer but I am getting floating points numbers in Y axis(hits) as per the attached graph and I am completely baffled as to how do i interpret this graph.

Logstash agent configuration

```
input {
  file {
    type => nginx_web
    path => ["/var/log/nginx/access.log"]
  }

filter {
 grok {
   type => nginx_web
   pattern => "%{IP:ClientIP} (?:%{HOST:ClientHost}|-) (?:%{USER:ClientUser}|-) \[%{GREEDYDATA:TimeStamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:Verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:Request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:HTTPversion}|%{DATA:UnparsedRQ})\" %{NUMBER:Response} (?:%{NUMBER:Bytes}|0) (?:%{QUOTEDSTRING:HTTPReferrer|\"-\"}) %{QUOTEDSTRING:HTTPUserAgent}"
 }

output {

 statsd {
        type => "nginx_web"
        host => "X.X.X.X"
        increment => [
                        "nginx.response.%{Response}"
                     ]
    }
}
```

I am using following URL API to generate this graph

```
render/?width=600&height=320&hideLegend=1&from=-60minutes&until=-0minutes&target=stats.logstash.*.nginx_web.response.*
```

[image]

*Can somebody point me in right direction as to where to go to remedy my issue ?*

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an old question (at the time of this answer), I'm just throwing this here as a reference for anyone else wondering the same thing.

Logstash's cookbook has an entry on understanding Graphite and how the data gets aggregated. See it [here](http://cookbook.logstash.net/recipes/statsd-metrics/)

If you happen to be using a newer version of logstash, then you'll have the **statsd_count** folder, which will give you the number of increments that Graphite received, instead of averaging it out over 10sec. for you.

Per the logstash cookbook [entry](http://cookbook.logstash.net/recipes/statsd-metrics/), assuming you have 3 200 responses within a frame of 10 seconds, statsd would produce something alone the lines of:

`stats.logstash.101010_1.apache.site1.response.200 = 3 / 10 = 0.3 (number of responses with status 200 per second)`

However, in the **statsd_count** folder, you would see something along the lines of:
`stats_count.logstash.101010_1.apache.site1.response.200 = 3 (we have received 3 times status 200 for our period of 10 seconds)`

Answer (score 0):

Values on your graph is not integer, since it is average values.

statsd stores integer values of response counter to show a point on graph it reduces earlier counter value from later and divides it by step time. (Count(t)-count(t-step))/step.

Comment: so then how do i draw the graph(like above) that makes sense ?

Comment: graph based on log message will not make much sense anyway, due to log buffering.Write a plugin to statsd that get values from nginx stub_status module, or use [nginx-statsd](https://github.com/zebrafishlabs/nginx-statsd)